How can a segment show more users than the Total in Looker?
I’m analyzing GA4 data in Looker and ran into something strange.
I grouped users by page paths using this logic:
CASE
  WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Page path and screen class, '/usa/') THEN 'usa'
  WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Page path and screen class, '/pri/') THEN 'pri'
  WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Page path and screen class, '/dom/') THEN 'dom'
  ELSE 'other'
END

Here’s the screenshot for context:

In the results:

Total Users = 12,503 (imported directly from GA4).
The “USA” segment alone shows 27,724 users, which is more than the total!

Has anyone seen this before? How can a segment have more users than the total?
